# Which is our canonical 'which' question?

Tags: discussion

A frequently asked question is: `which foo` tells me something, but it doesn't correspond to what happens when I actually run `foo`, what's going on?

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/how-to-determine-which-executable-on-my-path-will-be-run) is a recent example, but we've had many more — basically anything in the [which](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/which) tag, and more that should all be in the [path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) tag.

Is there one that we can consider to be canonical, so we can close the others as duplicates? Here, canonical means an answer that explains that `which` doesn't use the running shell's `PATH` and the asker should use `type` instead.

If we don't have one already, let's make one, possibly by editing an existing question.

Comment: I just started a canonical answers thread [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2708/22222).

Answer (score 3):

Should we not start a big [canonical page](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) like on server fault instead?

Comment: Have you got a link to that?

Comment: @ire_and_curses I added the link to my answer.

Comment: Wow, that looks really useful. +1.

Comment: The canonical page for `which` questions would be linked from the [tag:which] tag wiki, the problem isn't finding a place to link it. I was asking whether we already had a question that we considered a canonical `which` question.

Comment: @Gilles I thought you take a look at every question here. ;-) But IMHO your link in your question for the "recent example" looks good enough for me.